# how to pass path string variables with space to system command in R

Tags: r, string

When I try to copy files in R, the dir names with space come across to me. For example, I have a string variable `filname` with its value `c:/Datalogger Folder/Bdev.txt` and I want to copy this file to `A.txt`. I know that I should pass `filname` into `system` function:

```
   system(paste("cp",filname,"A.txt",sep=" "))
```

While for the reason that there is a space in `c:/Datalogger Folder/Bdev.txt`, the R complained that "c:/Datalogger no such file or directory". Please guide me how to resolve this problem. Thanks for any advise.

Comment: You need to escape the string with a ``\`` for `cp` to understand it: `c:/Datalogger\ Folder/Bdev.txt`

Comment: how to process variable filname? I cannot add `\ ` into this variable.

Comment: I'd just delete ` Folder` and keep only `Datalogger`. I think having spaces in folders or filenames is not good practice and will only produce trouble

Comment: @Tung, Actually the files to be processed are transferred to me, I cannot always manually rename directory  as I need.

Comment: You can write a simple shell script to do folder name and file name cleanup before doing anything in R https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/223182/how-to-replace-spaces-in-all-file-names-with-underscore-in-linux-using-shell-scr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add escape character `\` before spaces in `filname` using `gsub()`. For example:

```
filname <- gsub(" ", "\ ", filname)
```